# Getting undefined key value return when getting object value

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my nodejs project I'm fetching data from my MongoDB and retrieve after querying with this code:

```
app.get('/:user_id', (req, res) => {
  Contact.findById(req.params.user_id, function (err, user) {
    if (err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    let user_temp = JSON.stringify(user)
    console.log("1 - ", user);
    console.log("2 - ", user.name);
    console.log("3 - ", user_temp)
    console.log("4 - ", user_temp.phone);
    res.render('userInfo', {user: user})
  });  
})
```

The log I get is this

```
1 -  {
  _id: 5f56a47d5a246e5ff8b67129,
  name: 'UserA',
  phone: '054523423',
  __v: 0
}
2 -  undefined
3 -  {"_id":"5f56a47d5a246e5ff8b67129","name":"UserA","phone":"054523423","__v":0}
4 -  undefined
```

When I'm trying to console.log those values before or after JSON.stringify I always get undefined. I've looked at other bugs and I can't seem to find an explanation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `let user_temp = JSON.stringify(user)` before his line what does `typeof user` give? I guess it is the string that's why it is undefined

Comment: @aRvi it's an object

Comment: tip: use `if (err) return res.send(err)` else `/foo` will break with various errors

Answer (score 1):

Ohh now I get it. It was a mongoose problem. Since I did not define `name` in the `Contact` schema but rather `username`, the mongoose apparently could not interpret the `Object.key` notation. I've changed my Contact model Scheme and now it works!